# accessing the memory of a foreign process

Tags: c++, c, memory, process, createremotethread

ive been reading around the website and googling to try and find a conclusive answer to what im trying to do, but i didnt find one that answers all my questions.

i have two processes. one has an integer variable which i want to change by a second process. i know how to read/write to specific memory locations, but i only know how to do it on the native process addresses.

i dont understand createremotethread. is it possible i get the cleanest, simplest example of manipulating memory of a process not native to the running program? assuming both programs are running, of course.

thanks in advance

EDIT: i got some answers about my question from other sources. i just want to understand how do i write a vairable to a memory location, say:

WriteProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)address,val,sizeof(val),NULL);

this seems to have no effect, assuming the val is a bool:

```
while(true){
    key=getch();
    if(key=='1'){
        if(val)val=false;
        else val=true;
        WriteProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)address,&val,sizeof(val),NULL);
    }
    bool val2;
    ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (void*)address, &val2, sizeof(val2), NULL);
    cout<<val2<<endl;
}
```

always shows 0. why?

Comment: if `val` is an actual `bool` variable, then you need to use `&val` instead. But if `val` is already a pointer to a `bool`, then you don't need the `&`.

Comment: first thing, do this BOOL result = ReadProcessMemory, then output result, if result is 0 then something is wrong with either phandle, or address

Comment: did that, it returns a positive. nothing wrong with reading from memory it seems

Comment: when i do BOOL result=WriteProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)address,&val,sizeof(val),NULL);
   , it returns a 0 though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue solved, i had to use
    HANDLE phandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, pid)

instead of
    HANDLE phandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, 0, pid)

Answer (score 0):

try to read about shared memory, and mutex to make sure not two processes manipulating same memory spot at the same time.

```
BOOL WINAPI WriteProcessMemory(
  _In_   HANDLE hProcess,
  _In_   LPVOID lpBaseAddress,
  _In_   LPCVOID lpBuffer,
  _In_   SIZE_T nSize,
  _Out_  SIZE_T *lpNumberOfBytesWritten
);
```

did you pass the correct parameters as above, you will have to have at least the first 4 parameters to work

do the follow

```
WriteProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)address,&val,sizeof(val),NULL);
```

notice the val pass the address of the val

Comment: i did, the only question i have remaining is the usage of writeprocessmemory. i am unable to get it to work

Comment: doesnt work either

WriteProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)address,&val,sizeof(val),NULL);
int val2;
ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (void*)address, &val2, sizeof(val2), NULL);
cout<<val2<<endl;

always shows 0. why?

Comment: check the returning value, if 0, then some parameter is wrong